# How to determine file extension of downloaded content

Tags: perl, mechanize, content-type

I am downloading multiple files which may be of different types (eg. `PDF` or `TIFF`).  I would like to save the files with the correct file extension for each file.  I am able to look at the content-type header using:

```
$type = $mech->response->headers->header( 'Content-Type' );
```

Then I can work from there and make up my own file extensions based on the content-type found, but is there a `perl` module that already does this?  How else can it be done?

Comment: MIME::Type, MIME::Types and File::MimeInfo seem able.